# Compare two User Agents

Tags: c#, user-agent

We have a database which include thousands of user agents and their properties. I need to build an API on top of this database which receives a user agent, matches it with one of the existing user agents and then return its properties.

Obviously the first way of finding a matching user agent is to do an "exact" match. But in majority of times user agents have tiny differences that fails the exact matching.

I tried UA-Parser but I did not find it useful much as it normally fails to detect the "Device/Brand Name" and/or "Model Name".

Is there a way to tell if two user agents belong to same Device (Name and Model)?

Comment: What kind of info do you need that UA-Parser doesn't return?

Comment: Device Brand and Model name are the least properties that we need in order to match two user agents. However in many cases UA-Parser does not return the device name & model.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way you can parse device from user-agent as not all of them report it.

If you have a database with ready user-agents the best you can do is to use parser with suboptimal results and just embrace it.

There is parser compare repository with benchmarks for popular parsers.
https://github.com/diablomedia/useragent-parser-comparison

To save you time calculating - your best bet would be (for device detection and overall score): https://github.com/mimmi20/browscap-js

Here is their repo example:

```html
var Browscap = require('browscap-js');
var browscap = new Browscap();

var browser = browscap.getBrowser("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; WinTSI 05.11.2009)");

console.log(browser);
```

This is an example of output:

```html
{
  "Comment": "Chrome Generic",
  "Browser": "Chrome",
  "Browser_Type": "Browser",
  "Browser_Bits": "64",
  "Browser_Maker": "Google Inc",
  "Browser_Modus": "unknown",
  "Version": "0.0",
  "MajorVer": "0",
  "MinorVer": "0",
  "Platform": "Win10",
  "Platform_Version": "10.0",
  "Platform_Description": "Windows 10",
  "Platform_Bits": "64",
  "Platform_Maker": "Microsoft Corporation",
  "Alpha": false,
  "Beta": false,
  "Win16": false,
  "Win32": false,
  "Win64": true,
  "Frames": true,
  "IFrames": true,
  "Tables": true,
  "Cookies": true,
  "BackgroundSounds": false,
  "JavaScript": true,
  "VBScript": false,
  "JavaApplets": false,
  "ActiveXControls": false,
  "isMobileDevice": false,
  "isTablet": false,
  "isSyndicationReader": false,
  "Crawler": false,
  "isFake": false,
  "isAnonymized": false,
  "isModified": false,
  "CssVersion": "3",
  "AolVersion": "0",
  "Device_Name": "Windows Desktop",
  "Device_Maker": "unknown",
  "Device_Type": "Desktop",
  "Device_Pointing_Method": "mouse",
  "Device_Code_Name": "Windows Desktop",
  "Device_Brand_Name": "unknown",
  "RenderingEngine_Name": "Blink",
  "RenderingEngine_Version": "unknown",
  "RenderingEngine_Description": "a WebKit Fork by Google",
  "RenderingEngine_Maker": "Google Inc",
  "Parent": "Chrome Generic",
  "browser_name_regex": "/^mozilla\\/5\\.0 \\(.*windows nt 10\\.0.*win64. x64.*\\).*applewebkit.*\\(.*khtml.*like.*gecko.*\\).*chrome\\/.* safari\\/.*$/",
  "browser_name_pattern": "mozilla/5.0 (*windows nt 10.0*win64? x64*)*applewebkit*(*khtml*like*gecko*)*chrome/* safari/*"
}
```

This may not be related to the original post, but may be readers who look to parse UA can get better ways to achieve their needs:

1. If you need to track device (in physical sense, usually for security needs) - you should issue them a secret and use Secure remote password protocol to send you confirmation codes
2. If you have access to frontend development it would be easier for them to just report you this data, this is no less "secure" than user-agent header
3. If you need feature support list - MDN actually suggests to request feature support requests directly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent